# How to play sound with Ruby On Rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to play a sound in my app when a button is clicked. But nothing happens. I am using Javascript to play it.

I tried adding oof.wav in my assets folder. Not sure if it is right place to store it.

I already have a button like this `<button onclick="playOofSound()">OOF</button>` and I have this JS code

```js
function playOofSound() {
    var audio = new Audio('/assets/oof.wav');
    oofAudio.play();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue, and I just got it working. Here's what to do:

Add a new folder called 'audios' in your assets folder.
`/app/assets/audios`.

Now, insert your audio file into that folder, so in this case the full path would be:
`/app/assets/audios/oof.wav`

Now, on the HTML page you want to audio to play on, add this line of code:
`<%= audio_tag "oof.wav", id: "oof-audio" %>`.

When you want the audio file to play out loud on the browser, run this line of javascript code:
`document.getElementById('oof-audio').play();`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This solution should help 
[Playing sound in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397382/playing-sound-in-rails)

you can also check this
https://howilearnedrails.wordpress.com/2014/08/25/play-audio-file-on-button-click-in-rails/

```
$(".audioButton").on("click", function() {
  $(".audio-play")[0].currentTime = 0;
  return $(".audio-play")[0].play();
});
```